# How to check field data is numeric when using inline Script in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Per our requirement we need to find the max ID of the document before adding new document. Problem here is doc may contain string data also So had to use inline script on the elastic query to find out max id only for the document which has integer data otherwise returning 0. am using following inline script query to find max-key but not working. can you help me onthis ?.

```
{
  "size":0,
  "query":
  {"bool":
    {"filter":[
      {"term":
        {"Name":
          {
            "value":"Test2"
          }
        }}
          ]
    }},
          "aggs":{
            "MaxId":{
              "max":{
                "field":"Key","script":{
                  "inline":"((doc['Key'].value).isNumber()) ? Integer.parseInt(doc['Key'].value) : 0"}}
            }
          }
}
```

Comment: "Not working" means it throws an error (if yes please share) or it doesn't return any document? Can you share a sample document and your mapping?

Comment: I am getting following exception : error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Expected numeric type on field [Key], but got [string]"
         }
      ],   - I thins this is coming because isNumeric call on inline script is not working. do you have any idea what I am missing here ?. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: The error is because the `max` aggregation only supports numeric fields, i.e. you cannot specify a string field (i.e. `Key`) in a `max` aggregation. Simply remove the `"field":"Key"` part and only keep the script part

Comment: Wow. Its working. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the max aggregation only supports numeric fields, i.e. you cannot specify a string field (i.e. `Key`) in a max aggregation.

Simply remove the `"field":"Key"` part and only keep the script part

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "Name": "Test2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "MaxId": {
      "max": {
        "script": {
          "source": "((doc['Key'].value).isNumber()) ? Integer.parseInt(doc['Key'].value) : 0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```